# can't set max height with respect to screen heigth of a div with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

i'm using bootstrap with Django and i've been trying to set the max height of a div = 75% of the screen height because it has a large picture in it. so i'm trying to resize the parent div of the image to 75% of the device screen but this doesn't seem to work. i've used `class="mh-75"` and it doesn't work. i went further to load static css file to style this with `max-height: 75%;` and it still doesn't work. here's the code:

```
{% extends 'testapp/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for image in Image %}
        <div class= "container-fluid pd-2 pt-2 mh-75">
            <div class="bg-dark text-white rounded p-1">
                <img class="img-responsive img-wid img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.name }}">
                <div class="pt-2 text-center"><p>Source: {{ image.source }}</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

i don't think this would help but `img-wid` style:

```
.img-wid{
    max-width: 99.999%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `div` that acquire's the 100% of the screen and then use bootstrap to get the 75% if it as:

```
.main-container{
  height: 100vh;
}

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="h-75">
    //Your stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can also use bootstrap's `vh-100` class